# Getting NULL in nested case in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Please see my query first:

```
RecUPC=(case isnull(tm2.TranslationCriteria2,'') when '' then tm.TranslationCriteria2 
else (Case isnull(tm.TranslationCriteria2,'') when '' then rec.UPC end) end),
```

I am trying to get UPC if it is found in any of alias of `tm2` or `tm` or `rec`. But its showing most values as `NULL` where `tm2` contains most of values. 
So my doubt is why I am getting `NULL` when I have in these.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code contains some non-ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **SQL SERVER**:

You can make use of [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
RecUPC=COALESCE(tm2.TranslationCriteria2, tm.TranslationCriteria2, tm.TranslationCriteria2,'')
```